Add a symbol centered vertically between two tikzpicture
I would like to be able to add an arrow between two parts of an image, centered relative to the other two parts of my image.
My initial idea was to create 3 tikzpictures: one for the left diagram, one for the arrow and one for the right image. When I change the vertical value of the arrow, to center it, it stays at the bottom.

How can I do this?
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
        
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw back of vessel 1
        \draw (0,0) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0);
        \draw[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5] (0,-0.5) to
        [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,-0.5);
        
        
        %Draw front of vessel 1
        
        \draw (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0);
        \draw (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0)
        -- (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0);
        
        %Second part
        
        \draw (0,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)
        and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,-0.5);
        \draw[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5] (0,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)
        and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,-0.5)
        -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);
        
        %Draw back of vessel 2
        
        
        \draw[very thick] (-0.2,0.5) -- (2,-2);
        \draw(0,0.65) node{\small{\ch{Pt}}};
        
        \draw (1,-2) node {\small{\ch{H2O2}}};
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->](0,3) -- (1,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw back of vessel 1
        \draw (0,0) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0);
        \draw[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5] (0,-0.5) to
        [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,-0.5);
        
        
        %Draw front of vessel 1
        
        \draw (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0);
        \draw (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0)
        -- (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0);
        
        %Second part
        
        \draw (0,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)
        and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,-0.5);
        \draw[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5] (0,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)
        and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,-0.5)
        -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,40}
            \draw[fill=cyan!50] (0.85*rand+1,1.1*rnd-2.1) circle[radius=0.05*rnd+0.05];
    
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


For example add [baseline=1.5cm] to the second tikzpicture.

You can add baseline=1.5cm as option to the middle tikzpicture or use anchors such as (current bounding box.center) to vertically center all three pictures. Also see: How to vertically center-align an inline tikzpicture
But, actually, why not just put everything in one single tikzpicture? You could make use of a \pic in order to simplify drawing the vessel (which I made transparent):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{chemmacros}

\tikzset{
    pics/vessel/.style={
        code={
            \draw (0,0) to[controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0)
                (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0) -- 
                (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0)
                (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);
        }
    }
}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic at (0,0) {vessel};
        
        \draw[very thick] (-0.2,0.5) -- (2,-2);
        \draw (0,0.65) node {\small{\ch{Pt}}};
        \draw (1,-2) node {\small{\ch{H2O2}}};

        \draw[->] (2.25,-1) -- (3.25,-1);

        \begin{scope}[shift={(3.5,0)}]
            \pic at (0,0) {vessel};
    
            \foreach \i in {1,...,40} {
                \draw[fill=cyan!50] ({0.85*rand+1},{1.1*rnd-2.1}) circle[radius={0.05*rnd+0.05}];
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


